# Pinned Websites with Windows7 / IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 introduced the feature of pinned Websites (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/pin-a-website-to-your-taskbar)

Is there any possibility to have the same effect with IE8?

Comment: Why not use IE9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without third party software, no.

Technically, it is possible though. If you know C++, you can take advantage of the Taskbar's APIs to duplicate this functionality.

techie007's comment does warrant repeating. Why not use IE9? All the cool kids are doing it.

Comment: Is there any existing 3rd party sofware? Not yet IE9, because of corp environment